# Tkinter Python: Inability to Configure 'readonly' mode with Entry Widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello stackoverflow community,

I'm working on a project where I am attempting to configure tkinter entry widgets as 'readonly' to prevent the user of the GUI from being able to write or modify the contents of the entry fields. When I set the 'state' attribute to 'readonly' using the code provided below, it 'grays out' the entry field as opposed to merely preventing the user from changing the fields' content. This is shown in the top-left entry field in the image below. Are there recommendations on how to fix this?

```
# Render canvas to contain tabular results from character table with scrollbars for GUI functionality

        self.character_records_canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.options_main_frame, width = 1150, height = 800)

        # Define properties of scrollbars to render on frame 

        self.scrollbar_vertical = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.options_main_frame, orient = tkinter.VERTICAL, command = self.character_records_canvas.yview)
        self.scrollbar_horizontal = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.options_main_frame, orient = tkinter.HORIZONTAL, command = self.character_records_canvas.xview)

        # Pack widget objects into main frame

        self.scrollbar_horizontal.pack(side = tkinter.BOTTOM, fill = tkinter.X)
        self.scrollbar_vertical.pack(side = tkinter.RIGHT, fill = tkinter.Y)
        self.character_records_canvas.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT, fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand = 1)

        # Configure canvas to communicate with scrollbars
        
        self.character_records_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_vertical.set)
        self.character_records_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_horizontal.set)
       
        # Bind box around canvas to enable scrollbar functionality 
        
        self.character_records_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e : self.character_records_canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.character_records_canvas.bbox("all")))
      
        # Render child frame in canvas to display tabular results
        
        self.character_records_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.character_records_canvas)
        self.character_records_frame.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT, fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand = 1)

        # Configure the child frame to communicate with the canvas
        
        self.character_records_canvas.create_window((0,0), window = self.character_records_frame, anchor = "nw")
        self.character_records_canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.character_records_canvas.bbox("all"))

        # Return list of results from character database table

        query = "USE tictactoe_office_db;"
        self.db_obj.execute_query(query)

        query = """
        SELECT * FROM `character`;
        """

        character_results_list = self.db_obj.read_query(query)
    
        # Render table column headers on frame

        self.character_id_header = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame, state = 'readonly')
        self.first_name_header = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame)
        self.last_name_header = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame)
        self.branch_name_header = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame)
        self.game_wins_header = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame)
        self.game_losses_header = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame)
        self.match_wins_header = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame)
        self.match_ties_header = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame)
        self.match_losses_header = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame)
        self.match_total_header = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame)
        self.character_id_header.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "w")
        self.first_name_header.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = "w")
        self.last_name_header.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = "w")
        self.branch_name_header.grid(row = 3, column = 3, sticky = "w")
        self.game_wins_header.grid(row = 3, column = 4, sticky = "w")
        self.game_losses_header.grid(row = 3, column = 5, sticky = "w")
        self.match_wins_header.grid(row = 3, column = 6, sticky = "w")
        self.match_ties_header.grid(row = 3, column = 7, sticky = "w")
        self.match_losses_header.grid(row = 3, column = 8, sticky = "w")
        self.match_total_header.grid(row = 3, column = 9, sticky = "w")  
        self.character_id_header.insert(0, "character_id")
        self.first_name_header.insert(0, "first_name")
        self.last_name_header.insert(0, "last_name")
        self.branch_name_header.insert(0, "branch_name")
        self.game_wins_header.insert(0, "game_wins")
        self.game_losses_header.insert(0, "game_losses")
        self.match_wins_header.insert(0, "match_wins")
        self.match_ties_header.insert(0, "match_ties")
        self.match_losses_header.insert(0, "match_losses")
        self.match_total_header.insert(0, "match_total")          

        # Render tabular results on child frame

        for i in range(0, len(character_results_list)):
            for j in range(0,len(character_results_list[0])):
                self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame)
                self.entry.grid(row = i + 4, column = j, sticky = "w")
                self.entry.insert(tkinter.END, str(character_results_list[i][j]))

        # Render column header border labels

        for i in range(0, 10):
            self.character_records_menu_label_2 = tkinter.Entry(self.character_records_frame)
            self.character_records_menu_label_2.grid(row = 2, column = i, sticky = "n")
            self.character_records_menu_label_2.insert(0, "-----------------------------------")

        # Render "back" buttons

        self.options_back_button_1 = tkinter.Button(self.character_records_frame, text = "BACK", width = 10, command = self.destroy_character_records_canvas)
        self.options_back_button_1.grid(row = 47, column = 9)
        self.options_back_button_2 = tkinter.Button(self.character_records_frame, text = "BACK", width = 10, command = self.destroy_character_records_canvas)
        self.options_back_button_2.grid(row = 47, column = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `Label` instead of `Entry` if you want readonly text?

Comment: acw1668, thanks for the response. I'm using Entry because the formatting is cleaner for large amounts of tabular data. There isn't a need to hardcode border designs.

Comment: For your case, you need to set the `readonlybackground` option.  Also you need to set `state="readonly"` after inserting text.  It is better to define a custom `Label` class with the `border` and `relief` options set  with the desired values you want.